# Re-work Apache .htaccess to nginx configuration

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm trying rewrite my nginx to use `http://domain.com/main` instead of using `http://domain.com/?page=main`

I've done:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri;
```

Returns blank page

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/(\w+)+\/$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
if ($http_host !~ "^$"){
   rewrite ^(.*)$ http%1://www.$http_host$request_uri redirect;
}
```

Generates the url: `http://domain.com/main/http://domain.com/main/http://domain.com/main`

Here is the Apache .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Am I able to use a bump?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a working configuration for URIs of the form: `http://domain.com/?page=main`

The `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri;` may not work as expected as it will generate:

```
http://domain.com/?page=/main
```

Note the extra `/`. So you may need to use a rewrite to extract part of the URI not including the leading `/`. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}
location \.php$ { ... }
```

Note the `last` suffix rather than the `break` suffix, as the target URI needs to be processed in another location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.